# Executing javascript in the Address Bar in order to get & run a cookie's value

Tags: javascript, cookies

Let's say that I got a cookie just from browsing a website(which I do not own), and I know the cookie's name.
Now let's say I am on that website, going over to the address bar. My question is: Would I be able to display the value of that cookie after entering some sort of Javascript Code? or Any other code?

It's kinda Important for me to learn right now as I am studying websites. (And I know that I can get the cookies value with "Cookie Editor" and etc. I am just trying to get it through the address bar too).

Comment: `Cookie Editor` Wait what? You shouldn't use the address bar to execute scripts. Use the developer tools instead.

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:alert(document.cookie);` in Chrome's address bar works fine for me (it'll list all cookies for the current document). Note that for security reasons you have to type, not paste, the `javascript:` part.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to look for a specific cookie? and also to echo it on the browser's address bar itself? cuz' thats what I was trying to do...

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to learn here? What you're attempting to do doesn't seem like it's going to teach you anything useful.

Comment: I put a similar answer on user's other same question, before I saw this one:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135529/accessing-a-cookies-value-through-the-address-bar/16137024#16137024

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers can just show you the value of cookies for all sites you've visited (including the current one).  So, it's probably just easier to examine the cookie values there.  I know Firefox has a full built-in UI for displaying all the cookies for a given domain.  I suspect Chrome does too, but I'll have to look for that now to see if I can find it.

In Chrome, you go to:

```
Settings
Show Advanced Settings
Privacy/Content Settings...
All Cookies and Site Data...
Click on a Domain
Click on a cookie name
See the value for that cookie name
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than using the address bar you might want to look at the JavaScript console (CTRL+SHIFT+J for PC, I'm not sure about Apple). You can write JavaScript expressions there without having to use `window.alert()` etc.